# change header background based on average viewport color

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, html5-canvas

I'm looking for a way to change the background color, or/and opacity of a header element in a website based on the average color of the actual viewport. If the user is scrolling over a slider, or a colored fullwidth element, the header should be transparent or lighten up. If he's scrolling over a mostly white page with black text, the header background should darken.

I already saw, that there's a way to get the average color of a html5 canvas element, but that's not working with older browsers.

To simplify it: Would it also be possible to just recognize if the actual background-color behind the header is lighter or darker than a specified value and then lighten or darken the header background if necessary?

Comment: You can take an idea here: http://thesassway.com/intermediate/dynamically-change-text-color-based-on-its-background-with-sass

Comment: How old are the browsers it isn't working on. I'm guessing you mean browsers that don't support HTML5. If I were you I would just leave it as it is. That's just my advice, of course I may be wrong, you may have a very good reason for needing to support the older browsers.

Comment: Html5 canvas is the only way to calculate the color palatte on the client side. And canvas can even measure the lightness or darkness of the colors on the palette using HSL. So, AFAIK, the only client side fix is to test for the absence of html5 canvas (==older browsers) and, for example, put black letters inside a white backgrounded div on top of your page content. It's klunky (like old browsers are klunky) but it gets the job done.